# typo3 extension: what is the difference between exec_SELECTquery and SELECTquery?

Tags: typo3

I saw below codes in one extension file:

```
$res = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECTquery(
                    'fu.uid, fu.tstamp, fu.username, fu.usergroup, fu.email, fu.tx_jcregister_first_name, fu.tx_jcregister_last_name',
                    'fe_users fu'.$from,
                    $where,
                    '',
                    $markerArray['###SORT###'].' '.$markerArray['###ORDER###'],
                    $limit
                );
```

when I checked file: class.t3lib_db.php, I saw another function/method:

```
function SELECTquery($select_fields, $from_table, $where_clause, $groupBy = '', $orderBy = '', $limit = '')
```

so my question is:

what is the difference between `exec_SELECTquery` and `SELECTquery`? and when use `exec_SELECTquery`? when use `SELECTquery`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some more database operations put in single methods in this class, like `update`, `delete` and so on. They come paired, one with `exec_` as prefix. If you read the [documentation](http://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/47/html/classt3lib___d_b.html#a0e2963aab4b41e36f34b1f2228c66794) (which you do not, obviously), it is explained there very well for every method.

The methods **without** the `exec_` prefix all return a string, namely the query built. The `exec_xyz` all return a **query result** because the query has not only been built, but also **exec** uted, as the name implies.

```
function exec_SELECTquery($select_fields, $from_table, $where_clause, $groupBy = '', $orderBy = '', $limit = '') {
    $query = $this->SELECTquery($select_fields, $from_table, $where_clause, $groupBy, $orderBy, $limit);
    $res = mysql_query($query, $this->link);
    if ($this->debugOutput) {
        $this->debug('exec_SELECTquery');
    }
    if ($this->explainOutput) {
        $this->explain($query, $from_table, $this->sql_num_rows($res));
    }
    return $res;
}
```

If you just ignore the two `if`s for the moment, this method does nothing more than "wrapping" the query building with the execution of it. The two conditions are just for debugging.

BTW: I strongly encourage you to do some more research on your own, like google it, have a look in the documentation or just look a little deeper in the code. If you do not understand the small piece of code your question is about, I doubt that it makes sense for you to investigate a TYPO3 extension on this level detail for you as your latest questions imply (no offense).